# Dynamically loading Thor options for a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, dsl, thor

While trying to develop a simple gem to learn the process, I happened to stumble on this issue: *Thor* DSL takes in *options* to a *command* using the syntax: `option :some_option, :type => :boolean`, just prior to the method definition.

I am trying to have a dynamic set of options loaded from a file. I do this file read operation in the constructor, but it seems the `option` keyword for the *Thor* class is getting processed before the `initialize` method.

Any ideas to resolve this? Also it would be great if someone can explain how the option keyword works? I mean is `option` a method call? I don't get the design. (This is the first DSL I am trying out and am a total newbie to Ruby Gems)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thor'
require 'yaml'
require 'tinynews'

class TinyNewsCLI < Thor
  attr_reader :sources
  @sources = {}

  def initialize *args
    super
    f = File.open( "sources.yml", "r" ).read
    @sources = YAML::load( f )
  end

  desc "list", "Lists the available news feeds."
  def list
    puts "List of news feed sources: "
    @sources.each do |symbol, source|
      puts "- #{source[:title]}"
    end
  end

  desc "show --source SOURCE", "Show news from SOURCE feed"
  option :source, :required => true
  def show
    if options[:source]
      TinyNews.print_to_cli( options[:source].to_sym )
    end
  end

  desc "tinynews --NEWS_SOURCE", "Show news for NEWS_SOURCE"
  @sources.keys.each do |source_symbol| # ERROR: States that @sources.keys is nil
    #[:hindu, :cnn, :bbc].each do |source_symbol| # I expected the above to work like this
    option source_symbol, :type => :boolean
  end
  def news_from_option
    p @sources.keys
    TinyNews.print_to_cli( options.keys.last.to_sym )
  end

  default_task :news_from_option

end

TinyNewsCLI.start( ARGV )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of tweaking, I think I ended upon a solution that doesn't look too bad. But not sure placing code in module like that is a good practice. But anyways:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thor'
require 'yaml'
require 'tinynews'


module TinyNews

  # ***** SOLUTION *******
  f = File.open( "../sources.yml", "r" ).read
  SOURCES = YAML::load( f )

  class TinyNewsCLI < Thor

    default_task :news_from_source

    desc "list", "Lists the available news feeds."
    def list
      puts "List of news feed sources: "
      SOURCES.each do |symbol, source|
        puts "- #{source[:title]}"
      end
    end

    desc "--source NEWS_SOURCE", "Show news for NEWS_SOURCE"
    option :source, :required => true, :aliases => :s
    def news_from_source
      TinyNews.print_to_cli( options[:source].to_sym )
    end
  end

end

TinyNews::TinyNewsCLI.start( ARGV )
```